# IONIC Error when trying to custom a input file

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, input

Helo developers , im doing this IONIC app , and right now im trying to custom my Slect File input button in order to make it more user friendly.
In order to do that i bind that input to an image which might have the function of button inherited by that input file through a local reference .
Thus lets say this is my template:

```
   <form [formGroup]="editImageForm" (ngSubmit)="editImage()" #form="ngForm" *ngIf="imageSelected">

      <ion-item color="lightapppersonalized ">
        <ion-chip color="primary" mode="ios" outline="true">
          <ion-avatar>
            <img [src]="img|pipeImagen|async" />
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-label>{{imageSelected[0].url|pipeTitleFormat}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input style="display:none"  type="file" 
          placeholder="Awesome Input" (change)="selectImg($event)"
            formControlName="url" #imageUpload>
          </ion-input>
        </ion-chip>

        <ion-icon mode="ios" (click)='imageUpload.click()' src="./assets/edit.svg"></ion-icon>
    
      </ion-item>
      
      .....
   </form>
```

Literally the input file is set to visibility none at the same time a local reference is settled in it (#imageUpload)

then right beneath and icon( i tried also to set an image or button) is initialized with a click event referring to that local reference (#imageUpload) followed by a click method.
But for some reason the click over the local reference isn't well received
[image]
and once  i trigger the action in the app the appears error :

```
ERROR TypeError: _r2.click is not a function
    at EditImageSelectedComponent_form_8_Template_ion_icon_click_13_listener (template.html:29)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14316)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14351)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

as a clear reference to the icon where the click event is settled in my html tag.

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `imageUpload.click()` doesn't work, but here's how I customised a file input in my ionic app.

```
<div class="input-container">
    <div class="button-wrap">
        <label for="image-input" [className]="buttonClass">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="Image" style="font-size: xx-large; vertical-align: middle"></ion-icon>
            {{STRINGS.open_gallery}} {{images64.length}}/{{maxImages}}
        </label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" (change)="receivePhoto()"
               id="image-input" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 10px;
  left: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #b8b8b8;
  display: none;
}

.button-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.select-image-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response alex87, i keep trying to find a less invasive solution  from ionic.But this one also worked !!!

Comment: Not the neatest solution but glad you got it working. If my answer helped you please mark your question as solved.